# Display (errors, warnings, notices) of `define( 'WP_DEBUG', true );` in Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

It exists a posibility to display in `console.log()` the results (errors, warnings, notices) of `define( 'WP_DEBUG', true );`?

Comment: Well, you could read the contents of the [debug.log](https://wordpress.org/support/article/debugging-in-wordpress/#wp_debug_log) file with some PHP & AJAX and then output that via `console.log()`... but wouldn't it be easier to just read the file directly instead?

Answer (score 0):

You can add error dump in php and result will include all errors and warnings

```
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);
```

add this lines top of on your `index.php` file

note: use this only for development

Answer (score 0):

Yes @ cabrerahector

> Well, you could read the contents of the debug.log file with some PHP
>   & AJAX and then output that via console.log();

For displaying error,warning and notice on page , enable php error log via php.ini or using below php code on top of first php calling file.

```
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);
```

Comment: your answer will help me to see the data on the page, but how to see all these 3 details on console of the browser?

Comment: For displaying the these message on console, you need to put conditionally console.log as per these occours ( no direct method availble on php) .. for more detail you can see this link : https://stackify.com/how-to-log-to-console-in-php/